# VBA Goalseek with looped Goal

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a looped goal seek, where the set cell and changing cell are fixed in place, the only thing changing should be the goal.

In this case I have it in a for loop where the goal is referenced as Range("I" & i).

I am getting an error saying reference isn't valid

```
Sub OptimizeVal()
Worksheets("TRUCKING PRICING CALC").Activate
Dim i As Long
    For i = 50 To 64
        Range("E55").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("I" & i), ChangingCell:=Range("C75")
        Range("J" & i) = Range("C75").Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a goof... The cell being referenced, E55 was supposed to have a formula in it which I accidentally erased.

Final code.

```
Sub OptimizeVal()
Worksheets("TRUCKING PRICING CALC").Activate
Dim i As Long
    For i = 50 To 64

        Range("C54") = Range("H" & i).Value

        Range("E55").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("I" & i), ChangingCell:=Range("C75")
        Range("J" & i) = Range("C75").Value
    Next
End Sub
```